# Different results with find option and -mtime +7*365

Tags: linux, unix, find, aix

I am moving some scripts from AIX to RHEL and I have found a find command of a following format:

```
find -mtime +7*365
```

Has anyone experienced a syntax like above?

Replacing 7*365 with 2555 gives different results. And yes, I can't track the original creator of that script to ask personally.

EDIT:
I forgot about a '+' sign, apologies.
I have focused on multiplication in the -mtime value, but the full command is

```
find /path/ -mtime +7*365 -name 'SOME_NAME*.*'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if there's a file whose name starts with `7` and ends with `365` in the current directory, `7*365` is replaced by the name(s) of the matching file(s). To guarantee that `find` sees `7*365`, the wildcard needs to be protected, e.g. `find -mtime '7*365'` or `find -mtime 7\*365`.

Then I've never seen a find implementation that accepts arithmetic expressions. Only a non-negative integer in decimal (GNU find also accepts hexadecimal with a leading `0x`), with an optional leading `-` or `+`. The [AIX man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm) says that “a decimal integer” (with optional leading `-` or `+`) is required. I do't have AIX here to test, but with `7*365`, I'd expect an error, or if the integer parser is very sloppy it might be parsed as 7 or 0.

To look for files that were modified almost 7 years ago, you'd need to tell the shell to perform the arithmetic: `find -mtime $((7*365))`.

A modified version of what you wrote that *does* work is the following:

```
typeset -i interval
interval=7*365
find … -mtime "$interval"
```

It works without the quotes on `interval` too (as long as `IFS` doesn't contain a digit). The reason this works is that `typeset -i` declares `interval` as an integer variable. When you assign a value to `interval`, the shell performs arithmetic, so `interval` gets set to `2555`. This only works under ksh and bash, not under plain sh.

Comment: [GCC Compile Farm](https://cfarm.tetaneutral.net/) provides access to two or three AIX machines. You might consider getting an account given how much time donate to projects and authors.

Comment: On [GCC119](https://cfarm.tetaneutral.net/machines/list/), which is Power8 running AIX, `$ find -mtime 7*365` results in *`find: missing argument to \`-mtime'`*.

Comment: find /path/ -mtime +7*365 -name 'SOME_NAME*.*' works absolutely fine on the source system I am moving the script from

Comment: @kibicrealu1 What OS is it running exactly? You wrote that “Replacing 7*365 with 2555 gives different results”. So what does `7*365` do then?

Comment: @Gilles it is AIX 6.1.9.200 , +7*365 returns me a list of files, +2555 returns me nothing

Comment: @kibicrealu1 And are there files that are more than 2555 days old? It wouldn't surprise me if old AIX versions had a sloppy parser where `+7*365` is parsed as `+7` (lists files that are over 7 days old) or `+0` (lists all files whose modification time is in the past).

Comment: @Gilles it seems to work exactly as you wrote, many thanks! +7 & +7*365 return the same answer, sloppy parser it is then!